# Given a list of lists, how do I create a matrix of all possible combinations of values in Python?

Tags: python, combinations, permutation

I know how to create a matrix of combinations, but I want something more dynamic.  For example the below creates a matrix with all possible combinations of A, B and C:

```
A = [0, 1, 2]
B = [3, 5, 7]
C = [10, 20, 30]

MATRIX = []

for a in A:
   for b in B:
      for c in C:
         MATRIX.append([a, b, c])
```

I would like something that is more dynamic where I could have A, B, C, .....N lists.  All I have to define is the values within each list and then I want it to produce a Matrix of all possible combinations.

How do I do this?

Comment: [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

Answer (score 2):

Using [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) you can pass any number of iterables:

```
from itertools import product
print(list(product(A, B, C)))
```

output :

```
[(0, 3, 10), (0, 3, 20), (0, 3, 30), (0, 5, 10), (0, 5, 20), (0, 5, 30), (0, 7, 10), (0, 7, 20), (0, 7, 30), (1, 3, 10), (1, 3, 20), (1, 3, 30), (1, 5, 10), (1, 5, 20), (1, 5, 30), (1, 7, 10), (1, 7, 20), (1, 7, 30), (2, 3, 10), (2, 3, 20), (2, 3, 30), (2, 5, 10), (2, 5, 20), (2, 5, 30), (2, 7, 10), (2, 7, 20), (2, 7, 30)]
```

If you want to have a list of lists, not list of tuples, just write a simple "list comprehension".